# how to include .h document in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I am programming for a big project, so I cooperate with others. 
To make the directory easily managed, my directory is like below:

```
project:
--include (header files from others supplied for me)
--lib (libraries from others supplied for me)
--L3_CVS  (this folder include all my files)
   -- Makefile 
   -- sourceFile (all my source files here)
       -- include_private(all header files used only by myself)
       -- appl (all my C files here)
```

My Makefile is below:

```
####################################################
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/powerpc-wrs-linux-gnu/x86-linux2/powerpc-wrs-linux-gnu-ppc_e500v2-glibc_cgl-

EXTRA_CFLAGS += -g

EXTRA_LDFLAGS +=

LIBSB =-Wl,--start-group -ldiag -ldiag_esw -lacl -ldiagcint -lcint -lsal_appl -lsal_appl_editline -lsal_appl_plat\

-lbcm -lbcm_esw -lbcm_common -lfirebolt -ltitan -ltrident -lhumv -lbradley -lherc -ldraco -lscorpion\

-ltriumph -ltrx -ltriumph2 -lenduro -lkatana -lflexctr -lptp -lsoc_esw -lsoc -lsoc_phy -lsoc_mcm\

-lsoccommon -lsoc_shared -lshared -lsal_core -lsal_core_plat -lcustomer -lsoc_nemo -lsoc_clsbuilder\

-lsoc_sal \

-lbcm_compat -lbcm_rpc -lcpudb  -ltrx  -lstktask -llubde -ldrivers -ldiscover -lcputrans \

-lrcu -lpthread -lrt -lm   -Wl,--end-group

LIBS = -ldiag -lrcu 

CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc

LD = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld

AR = $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar

STRIP = $(CROSS_COMPILE)strip


SRC_PATH := ./SourceFile/appl

HEAD_PATH :=  ./SourceFile/include-private


INC_DIR  =  ../include

LIB_PATH =  ../lib


APP_NAME = L3appl

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)/*.c)

export $(SRCS)

OBJS:= $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS)) 

%.d: %.c

    @set -e; rm -f $@; \

    $(CC) -MM  $< > $@.$$$$; \

    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \

    rm -f $@.$$$$

sinclude $(SRCS:.c=.d)

INCLUDES = $(wildcard $(HEAD_PATH)/*.h)

$(APP_NAME):$(OBJS)

    $(CC)   -c -I$(INC_DIR) $(SRCS)

    $(CC)   -o  $(APP_NAME) $(OBJS) -L$(LIB_PATH) $(LIBSB)  -lpthread -lrt -lm


.PHONY:clean

clean: 

    rm   -f  $(OBJS) $(APP_NAME) 
#################################################
```

My problem is that when I run make in terminal, it always show : ***No such file or directory
compilation terminated. which seems the .h files in ./SourceFile/include-private do not be included.

But, in fact, I have use "INCLUDES = $(wildcard $(HEAD_PATH)/*.h)" include these .h files.

I don't know where is wrong!

this is my first time to write makefile. So if there are mistakes in my makefile, I would appreciate that you would point them out !

thank you for your help very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change `$(CC)   -c -I$(INC_DIR) $(SRCS) to $(CC)   -c -I$(INC_DIR) -include $(INCLUDES) $(SRCS)`

or $(CC)   -c -I$(INC_DIR) $(SRCS) to $(CC)   -c -I$(INC_DIR) -I$(INCLUDES) $(SRCS)
where INCLUDES is ./SourceFile/include-private (only the directory, no .h files)

Edit: Usually you don't have to explicitly include the .h files, but that's what the first change do. The second change does not add the .h files explicitely but provide the compiler another include directory where it could search for necessary .h files.

Refer to GCC man file for more info.

Regards

Comment: Try: $(CC) -include $(INCLUDES) -c -I$(INC_DIR) $(SRCS), i think i messed up the param order

Comment: $(CC) -c -I$(INC_DIR) -I$(INCLUDES) -I$(HEAD_PATH) $(SRCS) with .h file include in .c file responding to your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865965/how-to-include-h-files-in-c-files-if-i-use-makefile

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like

```
 CFLAGS = -Wall $(OPTIMFLAGS) $(INCLUDEFLAGS)
 INCLUDEFLAGS = -I $(INC_DIR) -I $(HEAD_PATH)
 OPTIMFLAGS = -g -O
```

You can use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile`.

Comment: Then use `remake -x` to debug your Makefile.