# how to include .h files in .c files if I use makefile

Tags: linux, gnu-make

I am programming for a big project, so I cooperate with others. To make the directory easily managed, my directory is like below:

```
project:
--include (header files from others supplied for me)
--lib (libraries from others supplied for me)
--L3_CVS  (this folder include all my files)
   -- Makefile 
   -- sourceFile (all my source files here)
       -- include_private(all header files used only by myself)
       -- appl (all my C files here)
```

if I want to include a .h file in my .c file, do I need to write in .c file "   #include "../include-private/XX.h"  "??? 
what if i just write in .c " include "XX.h"  "?

Because I need to use the .h files in "include folder" which others supply for me, how could I write in my .c files to include these .h files??

my makefile is below:

[how to include .h document in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857949/how-to-include-h-document-in-makefile)

thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the compiler, but typically, you'll want to add the following line:

```
 CFLAGS += -I../include-private
```

`CFLAGS` is a variable that make uses to add command-line options for the C compiler ("C" flags).  For C++, you need to use `CXXFLAGS`.  If I'm using C and C++ in the same project, I'll typically create a variable called `INCLUDES`, and use it like this:

```
 INCLUDES = -I../include-private

 CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
 CXXFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)
```

Comment: as you mean, I don't need write #include "../include-private/XX.h" in my .c file and just write INCLUDES = -I../include-private  CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES) in makefile?????

Comment: @city: No, you'll still have to include the header files in you c file. The `CFLAGS` just tell the compiler where to find this header files.

Comment: @city If you use that flag, then in the source you just need to include "XX.h", you don't need the path any more.

Comment: @ blueshift, what if there are many folders where contain different .h files  and these folders all belong to "include folder", how can I write in my makefile to let the gcc to search these folders which are under include folder? In my test, gcc just search include folder ,do not get into these folders.